# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1594338739818/work'

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, deployment

While deploying my website on heroku. I also updated my requirements.txt file still there is this issue.
`git push heroku master`

```
Enumerating objects: 98, done.
Counting objects: 100% (98/98), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (87/87), done.
Writing objects: 100% (98/98), 1.31 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 98 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.12
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.12
remote:          Downloading alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
remote:        Collecting appdirs==1.4.4
remote:          Downloading appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting argh==0.26.2
remote:          Downloading argh-0.26.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
remote:        Processing /tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1594338739818/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/asgiref_1594338739818/work'
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 9782a444fca0b0d09e0566b33ecbffce4eb90d89
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 9782a444fca0b0d09e0566b33ecbffce4eb90d89
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to blogshome.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/blogshome.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/blogshome.git'
```

The requirements.txt file contains colorama==0.4.3
Django==2.2.5 django-appconf==1.0.4 django-crispy-forms==1.9.1 django-multiselectfield==0.1.12 django-phone-field==1.8.1 django-phonenumber-field==4.0.0 django-select2==7.4.2 django-xhtml2pdf==0.0.4 graphviz==0.13.2 gunicorn==20.0.4 html5lib==1.1 idna==2.9 isort==4.3.21 lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3 mccabe==0.6.1 phonenumbers==8.12.5 Pillow==7.2.0 pylint==2.5.3 PyPDF2==1.26.0 pytz==2019.3 reportlab==3.5.48 requests==2.23.0 six==1.15.0 soupsieve==2.0.1 sqlparse==0.3.1 toml==0.10.1 urllib3==1.25.9 virtualenv==16.7.9 webencodings==0.5.1 wrapt==1.12.1 xhtml2pdf==0.2.4

Can somebody help and provide me an solution. Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the .git folder from my project directory and then used
git init to create a new one.
.git folder is actually hidden in the main directory so, first unhide and then delete it.
Also use pip freeze to get all requirements.